# Matching 1980s address data to 1990 census geoid10?

Tags: us-census, census, programming

I am hoping to match a list a addresses gathered in the mid 1980s with block group codes from the 1990 census. The geocoder on the census website processes this for 2010 block group designations only. Are there any other utilities or programs that can do this? I plan to do most the data processing in R if there are perhaps any packages that can help with this.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is to use QGIS or ArcGIS and perform a [spatial join](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86444/how-to-spatially-join-polygon-fields-onto-a-point-layer-in-qgis).

You could use the 1990 Census Block Group shapefiles located [here](http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/PREVGENZ/bg/bg90shp/) with your addresses/point data.